# C++0x lambdas with template parameters?

Tags: templates, lambda, metaprogramming, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can lambda functions be templated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575901/can-lambda-functions-be-templated)

Is it possible to have a c++0x lambda with template parameters? For example:

```
template <typename T> [=](const T *x) {}
```

What I am trying to do is to code a static for loop on a type list (variadic argument list), and I want to pass the current type as a parameter to to the operator () of the target functor (or lambda).

Answer (score 1):

That's called polymorphic lambda, I already asked about it there : [Can lambda functions be templated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575901/can-lambda-functions-be-templated)

And no it's not possible in C++0x. Maybe the next one.

However [boost::phoenix](http://boost-spirit.com/dl_docs/phoenix-2/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html) allows this so it might be a good workaround.