# How can I store a lambda expression as a field of a class in C++11?

Tags: c++, class, lambda, c++11, field

I'd like to create a class where the client can store a lambda expression like `[]() -> void {}` as a field of the class, but I can't figure out how to do so.  [One answer suggested using `decltype`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849247/34537), which I tried with no success.   Here is a [ideone source link](http://ideone.com/9fC2K). The below is the source and result:

```
#include <cstdio>
auto voidLambda = []()->void{};

class MyClass {
public:
     decltype(voidLambda) t;
     MyClass(decltype(voidLambda) t) { 
        this->t = t;
     }
};

int main() {
   MyClass([] {
      printf("hi");
   });
}
```

Result:

```
prog.cpp: In constructor 'MyClass::MyClass(<lambda()>)':
prog.cpp:3:79: error: no matching function for call to '<lambda()>::__lambda0()'
prog.cpp:2:20: note: candidates are: <lambda()>::<lambda>(const<lambda()>&)
prog.cpp:2:20: note:                 <lambda()>::<lambda>(<lambda()>&&)
prog.cpp:3:88: error: no match for 'operator=' in '((MyClass*)this)->MyClass::t = t'
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:5:27: error: no matching function for call to 'MyClass::MyClass(main()::<lambda()>)'
prog.cpp:3:48: note: candidates are: MyClass::MyClass(<lambda()>)
prog.cpp:3:14: note:                 MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Every lambda expression creates it's own unique type. In `auto A = [](){}; auto B = [](){};` `A` and `B` are not the same type.

Comment: Unfortunately `struct A { auto x = 0; };` is not allowed.

Comment: @bames53, I feel like your comment deserves 1000 more upvotes. Your comment is critical for understanding this adjacently-related question and answer too: [Is there a way to create a hash of a function wrapped by `std::function<>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76114883/4561887)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you want a class member to be a lambda expression, consider using the `std::function<>` wrapper type (from the `<functional>` header), which can hold any callable function.  For example:

```
std::function<int()> myFunction = [] { return 0; }
myFunction(); // Returns 0;
```

This way, you don't need to know the type of the lambda expression.  You can just store a `std::function<>` of the appropriate function type, and the template system will handle all the types for you.  More generally, any callable entity of the appropriate signature can be assigned to a `std::function<>`, even if the the actual type of that functor is anonymous (in the case of lambdas) or really complicated.

The type inside of the `std::function` template should be the function type corresponding to the function you'd like to store.  So, for example, to store a function that takes in two `int`s and returns void, you'd make a `std::function<void (int, int)>`.  For a function that takes no parameters and returns an `int`, you'd use `std::function<int()>`.  In your case, since you want a function that takes no parameters and returns `void`, you'd want something like this:

```
class MyClass { 
public:
    std::function<void()> function;
    MyClass(std::function<void()> f) : function(f) {
        // Handled in initializer list
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass([] {
        printf("hi")
    }) mc; // Should be just fine.
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Question: is `-> void` really necessary here ? I know the return clause can be omitted (and thus deduced) in a number of circumstances and this strikes me as begin an easy case (no `return`).

Comment: @MatthieuM.- I'm actually not sure!  I was under the impression that you had to have it, but if I'm mistaken I'd be happy to update this answer.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: If there is only one statement which is a `return`, the return type will be deduced. Otherwise, the return type is always `void`. Therefore, the `-> void` can be omitted.

Comment: Bye the way, you could even omit the parenthesis `()` since there are no parameters.

Comment: (lambda ->) is used to explicitly define a return type such that returns from the lambda have to comply. If you omit it then any number of returns can be in place but they all have to associate to the same type or you will get a compile error.

Comment: Why don't people include relevant includes in their answers? That would save me so much googling!

Comment: @TomášZato I've just updated the answer to include this detail. Thanks for pointing this out - it didn't occur to me that this would be a tricky header to find.

Answer (score 15):

The only way I can think of to store a lambda in a class is to use a template with a helper `make_` function:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

template<class Lambda>
class MyClass {
    Lambda _t;
public:
    MyClass(Lambda &&t) : _t(std::forward<Lambda>(t)) {
        _t();
    }
};

template<class Lambda>
MyClass<Lambda> make_myclass(Lambda &&t) {
    return { std::forward<Lambda>(t) };
}

int main() {
    make_myclass([] {
        printf("hi");
    });
}
```

Comment: circumvents the need to specify template arguments by introducing this helper `make_myclass`. That is the [Object generator idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Object_Generator).

Comment: With C++17 CTAD `make_myclass` is no longer needed.

Comment: I'm trying to implement something of this sort in my program. How might I go about removing the helper function?

Comment: @James51332 just `MyClass my ( []{ printf("hi"); } );`

Comment: thanks. lol. I figured out a more desirable implementation for this a long time ago (type erasure) but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In case of `[]` (empty capture) simple function pointer can be used. Declaration syntax is `ReturnType (*pointer_name) (Arg1T, Arg2T);` for pointer, `ReturnType (&ref_name) (/*void*/);` for reference (can't be null). Lambda with empty capture block is implicitly convertible to function pointer with same signature. And `std::function` have runtime and size (it is at least three times larger) overhead.

```
struct S
{
  void (*f_p)() {}; // `{}` means `= nullptr`;
};

int main()
{
    S s { [] { std::cout << "Lambda called\n"; }};

    s.f_p();

    S s2;
    if (s2.f_p) // check for null
        s.f_p();

    s2.f_p = [] { std::cout << "Lambda2 called\n"; };
    s2.f_p();

    s2.f_p = std::terminate; // you can use regular functions too

    s2.f_p();
}
```

Output

```
Lambda called
Lambda2 called
terminate called without an active exception
```