# Invalid expression in requires clause

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Is the expression `b<[]{ return true; }()>` within the requires-clause in accordance with the C++20 standard? For some reason GCC rejects it and deems it to be an expression error, while MSVC and Clang accept it.

```cpp
template<bool B>
inline constexpr bool b = B;
static_assert(requires { b<[]{ return true; }()>; });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/69Kssczr1)

---

GCC's error message:

```cpp
<source>:3:15: error: static assertion failed
    3 | static_assert(requires { b<[]{ return true; }()>; });
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:3:15: note: constraints not satisfied
<source>:3:26: note: the required expression 'b<<expression error> >' is invalid,
because
    3 | static_assert(requires { b<[]{ return true; }()>; });
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Looks invalid to me. The require clause doesn't come within any template and so there is no substitution of any template parameters.  Basically I think because the requires here isn't in any **templated entity**.

Comment: For example once it is nested inside a templated entity, the program compiles with all compilers. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yhaf8fq5G)

Comment: requires needs something to work on, a template function (or function with auto arguments) or a template class/struct. It looks like you are trying to attempt something, can you try to explain WHAT that is?

Comment: FWIW this works: https://godbolt.org/z/vMdeTPsjG

Comment: And, this answer might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849247/4358570

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a confirmed GCC [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113925). A requires-expression is a valid expression for a static assertion. The standard is wild in how deep the grammar goes, but here we go.

Per the grammar:

- [static_assert-declaration](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:static_assert-declaration) may consist of a
- [constant-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#nt:constant-expression) may consist of a
- [conditional-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#nt:conditional-expression) may consist of a
- [logical-or-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.or#nt:logical-or-expression) may consist of a
- [logical-and-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.and#nt:logical-and-expression) may consist of a
- [inclusive-or-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.or#nt:inclusive-or-expression) may consist of a
- [exclusive-or-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.xor#nt:exclusive-or-expression) may consist of a
- [and-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.bit.and#nt:and-expression) may consist of a
- [equality-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#nt:equality-expression) may consist of a
- [relational-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel#nt:relational-expression) may consist of a
- [compare-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.spaceship#nt:compare-expression) may consist of a
- [shift-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#nt:shift-expression) may consist of a
- [additive-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#nt:additive-expression) may consist of a
- [multiplicative-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#nt:multiplicative-expression) may consist of a
- [pm-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mptr.oper#nt:pm-expression) may consist of a
- [cast-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#nt:cast-expression) may consist of a
- [unary-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.general#nt:unary-expression) may consist of a
- [postfix-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.general#nt:postfix-expression) may consist of a
- [primary-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:primary-expression) finally may consist of a
- [requires-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:requires-expression)

The only question after that is whether (per [[decl.pre]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#11)) your provided requires clause satisfies the following:

> [the expression] E is contextually converted to bool and the converted expression shall be a constant expression

Well, a *requires-expression* is definitely convertible to a boolean, per [[exp.prim.req.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#req.general-2)

> A requires-expression is a prvalue of type bool [...]

Your *requires-expression* is a *simple-requirement* that just requires an expression that may or may not depend on template substitution. In your case, there is no template substitution, so all that's needed for the `requires` to pass is a valid expression, any valid expression. Your lambda is quite valid (and `constexpr`). Note, however, that a lambda returning `false` should be equally valid and cause static assertion to [pass also](https://godbolt.org/z/1cdMoj95W):

```
static_assert(requires { b<([](){ return false; }())>; }); // pass
```

Therefore it's probably not a good idea to use a requires expression without template substitution.

---

A funny thing is that a `static_assert` may also have a `noexcept` expression, and wrapping your requires clause in one makes [GCC 13.2 pass](https://godbolt.org/z/qd9K69hr1):

```
static_assert(noexcept(requires { b<([]{ return true; }())>; }));
```

Comment: Initializing a variable with the result of the requires clause (`bool z = requires { b<[]{ return true; }()>; };`) also seems to make GCC 13.2 accept it, while still being rejected by GCC trunk.

Comment: @303 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113925