# C++0x Variadic Parameter Pack: Syntax

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

the following code snippet won't compile under gcc4.6.1:

```
template <typename... TS>
void do_stuff(TS... ts)
{
  auto f = [](TS... things) { };
}
```

It throws an error stating that the pack things was not expanded. The following code does compile however:

```
template <typename... TS>
void do_stuff(TS... ts)
{
  auto f = [](TS... things...) { };
}
```

Notice the extra unpacking operator after things inside the parameter list. I've never seen a situation where a variadic pack had to be expanded during its declaration. So my question to you kind folks is:

Is this legal C++0x syntax (the snippet that compiles) or is it just a quirk with GCC when it comes to dealing with variadic types?

Comment: That isn't "capturing", capturing happens inside the `[]` brackets. You're just specifying an argument list. (But nice question!)

Comment: Thanks, I edited it to make more sense. I knew it wasn't capturing in the variable sense, but it seems like it's an issue with how the lambda "captures" that type TS...

Comment: Ah, I think I found the answer, which is "no": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575901/can-lambda-functions-be-templated

Comment: But the lambda function itself is not templated. When it comes time for the lambda expression to be evaluated, those types will be well defined.

Comment: Hm, right, disregard that comment. Actually, it seems that you can also say `doStuff(TS... ts...)`. I don't know if `(TS... ts)` is a permissible shorthand for member function declarations...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

- Yes, GCC is wrong to reject `[](TS... things) { }`. It's possible that it hasn't been implemented yet.
- What you declared by `[](TS ... things...) { }` is equivalent to `[](TS... things, ...)`. In C++ (not in C), you can leave off the comma before the C-style variadic ellipsis. So instead of doing `void printf(char const *fmt, ...)` you can declare `void printf(char const *fmt...)`. That's what happens in your lambda. The first ellipsis is the parameter pack unpacking, and the second ellipsis is the C-style variadic ellipsis.

Comment: That's very good to know, but how come `auto m = [](Args... p...) { printf("%d%d\n", p...); };` actually works in GCC 4.6 if I call `m(1,2);` and prints out `12`?

Comment: @Kerrek It's hard to second-guess. `-std=c++0x` is called *experimental* support for the next C++ Standard after all.