# Why Does C++1* Still Need the template Keyword in Lieu of Full Duck Typing

Tags: c++, templates, generics, duck-typing

Many years ago, (at least for me,) static C++ polymorphism seemed coherent. Languages such as Python relied on [*duck typing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), where you have:

```
def fn(foo, bar):
    foo.baz(bar.bo())
```

and the idea was that if it "quacked" appropriately, it was fine by the language.

In C++, conversely, you'd have to explain what "animal" it was:

```
void fn(foo_type foo, bar_type bar);
```

and for "kingdoms of families", you'd explicitly need to use the `template` keyword:

```
template<class Foo, class Bar>
void fn(Foo foo, Bar bar);
```

---

With new features like [`auto ...() -> decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) return types, but especially [generic lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575901/can-lambda-functions-be-templated), there appears to be something much more like non-template Python-like duck typing:

```
[] (auto container) { return container.size(); };
```

---

My question, then, is why is the `template` keyword still needed? Why not just fully embrace (optional) duck typing:

```
// Takes a foo_type and a bar_type 
void fn(foo_type foo, bar_type bar);

// Takes some "foo-quacking" type, and a bar_type
void fn(auto foo, bar_type bar);

// Etc.
```

Comment: Have you examined the concepts proposals for C++1z/C++2x?

Comment: @Yakk, thanks - I did not follow on where concepts are. Will read up.

Comment: It's coming, but not everything happens at once. In C++11 we got deduced return types for lambdas, then in C++14 we got them for all functions. In C++14 we got generic lambdas (i.e. `auto` parameters) and the Concepts TS adds the same for normal functions (such a function implicitly becomes a function template and gets instantiated for the supplied arguments).

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanWakely, that make sense.

Comment: Whether it's `auto` or `template`, you need some way to signal to the compiler that the declaration is not a concrete one, but a generic (parameterized) one. And that does leave the question which names are to be taken as parameters.

Comment: Regardless, _some_ terms are going to have to have a consistent, instantiated type. You won't get full dynamic / duck typing as in Python by complicating the template system. You might get closer to something like Haskell's heavily inferred type system where you can define your ducks (typeclasses).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually almost at the door as part of the [Concepts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) feature, and some compilers already implement it! For example, with GCC 4.9, if you specify `-std=c++1y`, you can actually compile and run the following:

```
auto print_arg(auto arg) {
  std::cout << arg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! was not aware of that at all.

Comment: And after this we'll get rid of `auto` keyword :)

Comment: @Pierre There's also some discussion going around, last time I checked, around simplifying range-based-for to simply `for (v : V)` which would likely be equivalent to `for (auto&& v : V)`.

Comment: Oh ok :) (I was just kidding, but ok) The C++ is going to be a script-like language...

Comment: It's not just "being discussed", it's an ISO Technical Specification. The feature you show is broken in GCC 4.9, but will be fully supported in GCC6 (along with the rest of the Concepts TS).

Comment: @YamMarcovic,  the [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm) shorter form of range-based `for` got rejected.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks, rephrased to be more accurate.