# Is it legal to explicitly specify a generic lambda's operator() template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer, generic-lambda

Is the following C++ code standard compliant?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    [](auto v){ std::cout << v << std::endl; }.operator()<int>(42);
}
```

Both *clang++ 3.8.0* and *g++ 7.2.0* [compile this code fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6534b6f121a1706) (the compiler flags are `-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`).

Comment: If you want to look it up, there's a copy of the standard [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4727.pdf).

Comment: AFAIK it is.  The lambda's `operator()` is public so I don't see anything that would stop it.

Comment: Read this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda. You can do it.

Comment: I know you do not have to give reasons in `language-lawyer`, but just out of curiosity, in which scenario you might want to?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you. I have a copy of the standard but I can't find the right place quickly enough.

Comment: @SergeyA It may seem strange but I want to use such construction in some code.

Comment: @Constructor I realize that. I was just wondering which code, but if are not willing to share, it's OK :)

Comment: @SergeyA, `template <class From, class To>
constexpr To nightmare_cast(From t)
{
 return [](auto v)constexpr{ return v; }.operator() < To > (t);
}` may the gods forgive me :)

Answer (score 17):

This is indeed standard compliant. The standard specifies there must be a member `operator()`, and that it has one template argument for every occurence of `auto` in its paramater-declaration-clause. There is no wording that forbids providing those explicitly.

Bottom of the line: The call operator of a lambda is just a normal function (template, if generic).

---

For reference, the relevant standard clause:

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression has a public
>   inline function call operator (16.5.4) whose parameters and return
>   type are described by the lambda-expression’s
>   parameter-declaration-clause and trailing-return-type respectively.
>   **For a generic lambda, the closure type has a public inline function
>   call operator member template (17.5.2) whose template-parameter-list
>   consists of one invented type template- parameter for each occurrence
>   of auto in the lambda’s parameter-declaration-clause, in order of
>   appearance.** The invented type template-parameter is a parameter pack
>   if the corresponding parameter-declaration declares a function
>   parameter pack (11.3.5). The return type and function parameters of
>   the function call operator template are derived from the
>   lambda-expression’s trailing-return-type and
>   parameter-declaration-clause by replacing each occurrence of auto in
>   the decl-specifiers of the parameter-declaration-clause with the name
>   of the corresponding invented template-parameter.

8.1.5.1/3 [expr.prim.lambda.closure] in N4659 (C++17), emphasize mine.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes, it appears to be well-defined** since template parameters for lambdas' `operator()` are strictly defined.

`[expr.prim.lambda]/5`

> ...
>   For a generic lambda, the closure type has a public inline function
>   call operator member template (14.5.2) whose *template-parameter-list* consists of one invented type *template-parameter*
>   for each occurrence of `auto` in the lambda’s *parameter-declaration-clause*, in order of appearance.
>   ...