# How to invoke a lambda template?

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates

I was able to compile the following code with gcc:

```
template<typename... Pack>
auto func(Pack... x) {
    return (x + ...) ;
}

template<typename... Pack>
auto lamd = [](Pack... x) {
    return (x + ...) ;
};
```

I can invoke the function template with `func(1,2,3)`, but I get an error when invoking a the lambda, with `lamd(1,2,3)` or `lamd<int>(1,2,3)`.

Comment: You should look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/3575901

Comment: It would be `lamd<int, int, int>(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second definition is a variable template. It does not define the lambda's `operator()` as a template, but rather takes the parameter pack for the argument types of `operator()`. The resulting `operator()` is a regular member function of the instantiated variable's closure type. There is no template argument deduction possible here.

So when you write `lamd<int>`, the variable gets a closure type with a `operator()(int)`, not something callable with 3 integers.

As mentioned already, you can use a generic lambda instead.

In C++20, if you'd need the lambda's argument types to be named and deduced, you can use the syntax:

```
auto lamd = []<typename... Pack>(Pack...) {}
```

This *will* define the operator as template, accepting a parameter pack, and leave the door open for template argument deduction.

Answer (score 5):

For lambdas, you can make it [generic lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) with the usage of `auto`.

```
auto lamd = [](auto... x) {
    return (x + ...) ;
};
```

Since C++20 you can uses an explicit template parameter list, but note that the template parameter list is still used with the `operator()` of the lambda, just as the usage of `auto` parameters. e.g.

```
auto lamd = []<typename... Pack>(Pack... x) {
    return (x + ...) ;
};
```

and then you can call it as `lamd(1,2,3)`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wcHTPwG7ZlgQiN0i)

Comment: Good answer. Just curious - Can I use a templatized lambda in general?

Comment: @Nujufas Answer revised.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a lambda template. A lambda expression is always of a unique, new type. In particular, it is not a template that can be used for instantiating actual functions.

The function call operator that a lamdba provides, however, can be a template. And you get the syntax for free, too:

```
auto lamd = [](auto... x) {
    return (x + ...) ;
};
```

Note that C++2a will ship with additional support and explicitness for generic lambdas and allows you to

```
auto lambda = []<typename...T>(T&& ...args) { /* ... */ };
```

but this doesn't affect the issue you were facing here.