# Is possible to invoke a templated lambda with explicit specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, visual-studio-2019, template-specialization

I'm trying to use a lambda which have two specializations, but it seems I'm doing something wrong. I tried to search here, but I couldn't find nothing, except this:

[How to invoke a lambda template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732722/how-to-invoke-a-lambda-template)

Which doesn't help too much in my case. Please, could you tell me how should I invoke lambdas with my specializations? I'm working with Visual Studio 2019 16.9.2 (I cannot update yet)

```
auto testLamb = []<typename T, int max = 2>(T data)
{
    if constexpr (max == 0)
    {
        return data;
    }
    else
    {
        return data + max;
    }
};

int f1 = testLamb<int, 4>(4); // Error C2062 !!
int f2 = testLamb(5); // OK!
```

Comment: *"which have two specializations"*, `data + max` is valid for both cases as `data + 0` is `data` (assuming no strange overloads for `T::operator+(int) /*const*/`) ;-)

Comment: Notice that you want to call a lambda template, whereas in the linked (misnamed) question OP wants to call a template variable initialized by a lambda (non-template).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the class/variable which is template, but its operator:

```
testLamb.operator()<int, 4>(4);
```

Comment: However, I tried following code and this failed compiling on gcc12.1 and clang14.0.
`template<int N> int f(){    auto testLamb = []<int max = 2>(){ return max; };    return testLamb.operator()<N>();}`. Why?

Comment: @KaiGu: It would be `testLamb.template operator()<N>()`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c8av5e11P)